# how to list only security update via pip

Tags: pip

With the recent change in `pip` having it upgrading packages `only-if-needed` by default (or using `--upgrade-strategy eager`) I would like to have pip listing only security updates of my packages in order to avoid upgrading modules for new features but to keep my system up-to-date regarding security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it. `pip` doesn't know what updates are what — security, bug fixes, feature releases. `pip` simply doesn't distinguish them.

You have to track release notes for all installed packages. There is no other way. I've heard there are commercial services that track security updates and notify you.